In ADF test, how do I specify non-linearity?
I have a time series exhibiting a non-linear relationship, with dips during recessions. I want to perform an augmented dickey fuller test to test for a unit root/stationarity. I'm not sure how, or if, I have to consider this in my ADF test, from what I know if we don't take into consideration non-linearity rejecting the null becomes difficult.
I'm trying to code it in python and the adfuller function from statstools doesn't seem to accommodate for non-linearity, and it only allows specifying the number of lags.
Which leads to my next question: do I also have to make sure to correctly specify the number of lags in my ADF test?

Hi: you'll have a  better chance of getting a response if you write down the non-model you are fitting ? But the short answer is that the ADF doesn't handle non-linearity.

@mlofton Thanks! Weird, from my lecture slides it said that for accurate adf test results non linearity has to be taken into account otherwise rejecting the null becomes difficult (obviously). Is there a way to maybe adjust for non-linearity?

There are variants of DF such as https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0304407602002026 accounting for certain forms of nonlinearity

Thanks Christoph for the info and link.
